# ImportError: DLL load failed importing spacy

Tags: python, windows, spacy

I'm trying to import spaCy in python (in Windows), but with no luck so far. I installed a virtualenv and with both pip and Anaconda spacy. No problems with installing the package, but when I import spaCy (in a Jupyter Notebook) I get the following error:

`[in] import spacy 
[out]
[...]
ImportError: DLL load failed: The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.`

When I run the input again the error messages is as follows:

`[...] ImportError: cannot import name util`

I'm not sure where to look for a solution. I thinking of a problem with version of other packages or maybe even with the Python version.

I'm currently using Python 2.7.13.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! It turned out that for running spaCy on Python 2.7 in Windows you need Visual Studio 2008:
https://spacy.io/docs/usage/#source-windows
It's not so easy to find it on microsoft website but the download link is here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336
Once you install it, spaCy should work.

Comment: More help in the spaCy github : https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1199

Comment: The link to the VC has been updated as of June 2019: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48145

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use anaconda, installing the latest Visual C++ Redistributable (vc_redist.x64.exe) works flawlessly for me.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Answer (score 1):

The Two things I needed to do to get spaCy working were:

> 1. Install VC2008 Redist (64Bit) I used this link: > 
>      http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20922.
> 2. When I installed the model (I used Anaconda) ensure that I ran the Prompt as Administrator

Finally you might want to try using Anaconda.
Works like a charm for me

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and can be resolved following those links :

https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1199
&
https://github.com/kbenoit/spacyr/issues/19

In a nutshell, it doesn't work because Visual C++ is not installed, and it uses the msvcrt90.dll that ships with Anaconda.